# MySql group by on second record

Tags: mysql

I have this query...

```
SELECT gallery.* FROM gallery INNER JOIN company_details ON gallery.com_id = company_details.com_id GROUP BY gallery.com_id ORDER BY company_details.adv_src_pos
```

when i run this in phpmyadmin it will show group by with first record of group but i want group by with second record of group. i search for it in stackowerflow there are example also but i don't know how to do it with particular query? and above query shows in phpmyadmin is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'd just replace

```
GROUP BY gallery.com_id
```

with

```
GROUP BY company_details.com_id
```

But, isn't the resulting view the same? Please clarify what you mean by "second record."

Comment: he is joining on that column, so how would it be different?

Comment: for example com_id=6 have 6 album and in above image it's displaying first album 30X60CM  IMPERIAL SERIES but i want second album. and i want it for all com_id.

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ - My thinking was either (1) he doesn't know that yet, and will find out, or (2) isn't using the term "record" properly in his question. I think it might be (1), and he's confused by seeing the same view, and thinking he has a syntax issue.

Comment: @DivyeshJesadiya - So, you mean you want to... skip the first record? Why? Can you edit your question perhaps to show us what your expected order of results would be?

Comment: i remove gallery.album ASC from query because it won't needed if this problem solved.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, try `SELECT gallery.* FROM gallery OFFSET 1 INNER JOIN ...`.